# R make new columns from uniqe values in column dynamically

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I want to create new columns based on unique values in one column dynamically. Original:

```
id, category
1, a
2, b
3, c
4, b
```

New:

```
id, category, a, b, c
1, a, 1, 0, 0
2, b, 0, 1, 0
3, c, 0, 0, 1
4, b, 0, 1, 0
```

For now I do:

```
data$categoryA = ifelse(data$category=="a", 1, 0)
data$categoryB = ifelse(data$category=="b", 1, 0)
...
```

But I want to do this dynamically something like this:

```
for(CATEGORY in unique(data$category) {
  data$CATEGORY  = ifelse(data$CATEGORY =="a", 1, 0)
}
```

Comment: I feel like this has been asked at least 45k times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use:

```
factor2binary=function(inputvar)
{
    set.l <- unique(inputvar)
x=(sapply(set.l, function(x) as.numeric( inputvar == x)))
colnames(x)=unique(inputvar)
x
}


A=sample(LETTERS[1:4],100,rep=T
factor2binary(A)

     D A C B
[1,] 1 0 0 0
[2,] 1 0 0 0
[3,] 0 1 0 0
[4,] 1 0 0 0
[5,] 0 0 1 0
[6,] 0 1 0 0
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

We can apply `table`, convert it to `data.frame` and `cbind` with the original dataset.

```
cbind(df1, as.data.frame.matrix(table(df1)))
#  id category a b c
#1  1        a 1 0 0
#2  2        b 0 1 0
#3  3        c 0 0 1
#4  4        b 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed code can't work because you are using `data$VARIABLE` to create a new variable in a data frame:

```
for(CATEGORY in unique(data$category) {
  data$CATEGORY  = ifelse(data$CATEGORY =="a", 1, 0)
}
```

This may work as intended if using

```
for(CATEGORY in unique(data$category) {
  data[[CATEGORY]]  = ifelse(data$CATEGORY =="a", 1, 0)
}
```